# signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, circleci-2.0

Build APK with circle ci 2.0, during build of debug apk this happnes. It used to work before , recently updated the sdk and compile target from 25 to 27.

Here is the error I get:

Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: signature-polymorphic method called without --min-sdk-version >= 26

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForMockDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.4.7/b4b263e2106bac49c2eb21f6737f9b6e45e24a4a/groovy-2.4.7-grooid.jar' to '/home/circleci/vhive-mobile/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/mock/debug/folders/1000/10/groovy-2.4.7-grooid_997a915e9e84ebe7f4f7e4cbba4ea1276c91d35f'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the build tools I used (which were upgraded from 25 to 27 ) caused this issue.
I downgraded them back to 25 and it solved the issue.